# HTML5 issue with c# offline storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a simple problem that the pages which has a html extension is offline stored but the pages with aspx can not be stored.
Im using c# and html5.
What i want exactly is 2 store this website as offline stored data.
Url : http://wt.telepaty.com/default.aspx ( This page cannot be stored )
Url : http://wt.telepaty.com/asdasdaddefault.html ( This page can be store and opened while im offline or disconnected ) 
Thank You In Advance

Comment: You mean cached by the browser or "offline stored" on some other way?  You'll need to provide more information or the question will likely get closed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="999" VaryByParam="cashId" %>
```

If you want client side to cache it, then that's the code for it.

Comment: what ? sorry but i did not understand or get what you mean . Where do i put this code in the masterpage.page ? or where ? and in case u wanna check : http://wt.telepaty.com/default.aspx

Comment: In's not allowed in *.master file. You will have to add it to context you want to be cashed. MSDN offers explanation about usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

Comment: it's totally different from cache offline storage. what's more, OutputCache is on server side, not client side